# SQL Server update column using other column's value

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a table column in SQL Server 2017. I have a table called `tbl_imm_data` where the column `imm_photo_path` contains the physical path to an image. I want to update the same tables column called `photobase64` to contain the actual image, so I tried this query:

```
UPDATE tbl_imm_data 
SET photobase64 = SELECT BulkColumn 
                  FROM Openrowset (Bulk imm_photo_path, Single_Blob)
```

For some reason, the `imm_photo_path` column name inside the `Openrowset` subquery is not recognised. Any ideas ?

Comment: `OPENROWSET` does not allow for *variables* or *column* values - the path has to be a **string literal**

Comment: i m so dumb you re right!